# ADFS2016 SAML2 to OAUTH2/OIDC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, saml-2.0, adfs4.0

We have an MVC application (<myapp.somedomain.com>) .net 4.5.2 (OWIN/ADAL) that uses ADFS2016 for AuthN/AuthZ via OIDC/OAuth2. Users' credentials and attributes are stored in AD LDS. A client (X) requested to authenticate in the application via their IdP over SAML2. Is this possible WITHOUT making changes to the application?

The flow I am looking for; for this client the app’s URL would be (<myapp.somedomain.com/?client=x>). Our ADFS would recognize and redirect the client to their IdP where they would authenticate and than they would be send back to our ADFS along with some predefined claims. Our ADFS would map these claims to an Id Token / Access Token for our application to use. Am I dreaming or is this indeed feasible?

Any links to articles / documentation on how this could be achieved would be most helpful.

Comment: Why won't you handle this between your app and client's idp? I'd recommend to eliminate adds from the picture for this specific client.

Comment: Because I would like to avoid making changes to the app just for this "edge" case. We have a plan to migrate to more powerful IdP later this year. Also, there are a few Angular based apps that the client might need to access. It would be difficult to get support for them over SAML2.

Answer (score 0):

As @Wiktor suggests, you could add a SAML [client-side stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) to your app.

The other way is to federate ADFS with the SAML IDP.

When the user is redirected to ADFS, they use Home Realm Discovery to either redirect to the SAML IDP or authenticate on ADFS directly.

ADFS should handle the token conversions but you may have to fiddle around with the claims rules.

Comment: So this is indeed possible? I would need to test it of course but do you see any reason why this should not work?

Comment: This could be tricky if the requirement is too have this for a single client in a multi tenant app.

Comment: Yes but the client has to pick the IDP (SAML or local ADFS) manually.

Comment: The problem I see is that ADFS OIDC doesn't do claims mappings well. So you may have issues mapping the SAML claims to OIDC ones.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Interested in why you think this could be tricky?

Comment: @rbrayb: what I understood from OP's question is that they want this additional IDP only for just one tenant (but not for other tenants). Somehow then, ADFS should render the home realm discovery conditionally (depending on the wtrealm possibly). I don't even know if this is possible with ADFS, also, this could change they way the app is federated with ADFS as each tenant should possibly be identified individually in ADFS (while at the moment it could be that the app redirects to ADFS the same way, regardless of the tenant).

Comment: @WiktorZychla You could filter on email address but local users will still see the HRD - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/home-realm-discovery-customization#configure-identity-provider-to-use-certain-email-suffixes